# Upgrading from ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 18.04 doesn't make up to Login Screen

Tags: boot, grub2, updates, lightdm

I updated ubuntu 16.04 LTS because on 16.04 every time I start my computer, The folders and files gets locked. I used to solve them with "fsck /dev/sdaX" where X denotes the Partition number i.e. sda1 , sda2 etc and restart my system but it would waste a lot of my time. I tried different ways to solve this issue but couldn't so I updated my OS with the hope that it would solve this issue.

When the updates were installing, in the middle the login tty1 screen appeared and I logged in and reboot the system because nothing happened after login. But when I rebooted, the system won't make up to Login Screen. Instead it's stuck on purple screen with one dot under ubuntu logo.

I tried recovery mode through GRUB, enabled network and selected root, entered root password but then when I run commands like "sudo apt-get remove plymouth", "sudo apt-get install lightdm" etc. They are not executed and the system suggests me commands but when I use to suggested commands, they aren't executed too.

(I know that it's duplicate but my problem is not solved from answers of the previous question like this one so technically it's not a duplicate. I am a software developer and I can't lose my data plus I need to get back to my development environment ASAP.)

Comment: if you cant lose your data then backup them. If you want to upgrade 16 to 18 or 19, youd better go for a fresh from scratch - And if there is filesystem issues, backup and go for fresh clean Ubuntu install.

Comment: Yeah, that would be the last resort. But the problem is I have a lot of IDE's and their components installed and I just don't want to reinstall them... That's why I am looking for a way to resolve this.